# Is it possible preserve original layout, when using templates in knockoutjs with foreach?

Tags: templates, knockout.js, jquery-templates

I have an issue when rendering templated items within a ul with some pre-defined `li` elements, that i'd like the templating engine to respect:

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<ul data-bind="{template: {name: itemTemplate, foreach: itemsToRender}}">
    <li class="first">some pre-info</li>
     //this is where I'd like knockout to render my templates
    <li class="last">som-post info</li>
</ul>
```

This is what I actually get:

```
<ul data-bind="{template: {name: itemTemplate, foreach: itemsToRender}}">
    //this is where all my templateItems get rendered
    <li class="first">some pre-info</li>
    <li class="last">som-post info</li>
</ul>
```

An obvious alternative is to use a template that rendered the entire `ul`, and looped over the child items, but this would render the entire template every time there was a change, and not just the updated items (`li`), which is the [preferred way](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_3_using_the__option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to use the containerless control-flow bindings available in KO 1.3 (in RC).

It would look like:

```
<ul>
  <li class="first">some pre-info</li>
  <!-- ko foreach: itemsToRender -->
    <li class="item" data-bind="text: name"></li> 
   <!-- /ko -->
  <li class="last">some post-info</li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
  <li class="first">some pre-info</li>
  <!-- ko template: { name: 'itemTemplate', foreach: itemsToRender } -->
  <!-- /ko -->
  <li class="last">some post-info</li>
</ul>

<script id="itemTemplate" type="text/html">
    <li class="item" data-bind="text: name"></li> 
</script>
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/tzJU3/

Comment: Didnt realize that 1.3 now was in RC. Will certainly have to take a look at it. Since i didn't specify that I'm currently using KO 1.2.1, I'll accept the answer...also doesnøt really seem like 1.2.1 can solve this. thanks :)